# SQL authentication in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

I have this problem.

I first connect(log) to SQL Server using SQL Management Studio the authentication is set to Windows Authentication.

Then I go to the Security => Logins folder and add a user, the authentication is: SQL Server authentication, I give him also the sysadmin role [all roles]

I try to login as that user, but I can't

I tried everything but no result

How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should enable SQL Authentication; it isn't enabled by default.

In SSMS, right-click on the top-level (server) node, select Properties.  Then click on Security in the left-hand panel, then select the "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" radio button in the right-hand panel.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to restart you sql server. For me it start working only after restart.